# how to create an image of a disk?

Tags: .net, filesystems, diskimage

I'm developing in .net, but can use c++.  I'm looking for a way to create a disk image.  Ideally there could be an API somewhere that looks like this:

```cs
createVMDK(string driveLetter, out string pathToVMDKOutputfile);
createVHD(string driveLetter, out string pathToVHDOutputfile);
```

Does anyone know of any API from Microsoft, VMWare or other that allows for the creation of full disk images like this?

Comment: +1 For a rather interesting question. I also wondered if there was some simple API function you could call to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no API, you can invoke [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) in a Process:

```
disk2vhd <[drive: [drive:]…]|[*]> <vhdfile>
```

Comment: Yes I found that tool.  Problem is that you can't redestribute it legally... MS isn't licensing any of the sysinternals tools... which means you can't really use it in a commercial / production application.  I guess I could make it a "pre-requisite" for installation, but given how MS isn't supporting it for that kind of usage (use from another app vs use from a user) I think that's pretty risky

Comment: So just thinking... is there any way to find out how disk2vhd is doing its work?  i.e. that is _precisely_ the functionality that I want...

Comment: I know it uses VSS, but don't know about the rest. Good luck ;)